# $parent ignored in knockout data binding

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I have a knockout viewmodel (written in typescript) which follows a recursive structure. A simplified version is as follows:

```
class ReportGroupViewModel {
    constructor(name?: string, subGroups?: ReportGroupViewModel[]) {
        this.name = ko.observable(name || '');
        this.subGroups = <KnockoutObservableArray<ReportGroupViewModel>>(ko.observableArray(subGroups || []));
    }

    name: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    subGroups: KnockoutObservableArray<ReportGroupViewModel>;

    addSubGroup(): void {
        this.subGroups.push(new ReportGroupViewModel());
    }

    deleteSubGroup(subGroup: ReportGroupViewModel): void {
        console.log(this.name());
        this.subGroups.remove(subGroup);
    }
}
```

In my view, I am using a recursive template to list the groups.

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'subGroupTemplate', foreach: subGroups }"></ul>
```

The simplified template is as follows:

```
<script id="subGroupTemplate" type="text/html">

    <span class="item-actions pull-right">
        <span data-bind="click: addSubGroup">Add Sub Group</span>
        <span data-bind="click: $parent.deleteSubGroup">Delete Sub Group</span>
    </span>

    <li>
        <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: name" placeholder="Name"/>
    </li>

    <ul data-bind="template: {name: 'subGroupTemplate', foreach: subGroups }"></ul>

</script>
```

The problem I have is that the deletion binding does not fire on the parent object, but on the child object (i.e. it acts as if the binding were `data-bind="click: deleteSubGroup"`, without the `$parent.`) as can be seen from the name which is logged out to the JS console. I've created a jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/po173qqh/3/

What am I doing wrong which is resulting in the deleteSubGroup method being called at the wrong level of the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inputting `$parent.deleteSubGroup` you reference the method in `$parent`. The method is still called with the `$data` as `this` though. You'll have to tell knockout it has to use `$parent` as `this` by binding:

```
<span data-bind="click: $parent.deleteSubGroup.bind($parent, $data)">Delete Sub Group</span>
```

Alternatively, you could use the `var self = this` pattern and use `self` inside your method, but I'm not sure how this works in Typescript...

**Edit:** It might be the fiddle typescript conversion, but I had to remove the `{}` inside `applyBindings` to fix it: https://jsfiddle.net/qf66w75p/

**Edit 2:** As Tsvetomir Nikolov suggested in the comments, you can also explicitly bind the function to the parent context by using an arrow function. Definitely the cleanest option. Thanks, Tsvetomir! https://jsfiddle.net/y9ax95fy/

Comment: Or he can use the arrow function instead of "vas self = this":

deleteSubGroup = (subGroup: ReportGroupViewModel): void => { }`

Comment: @TsvetomirNikolov, great suggestion. I haven't used Typescript so I didn't know it supported arrow functions as well. I added it to the answer, if that's okay with you.

Comment: The arrow function is the way to go, typescript changes the context of `this` in an arrow function and I'd forgotten about that. Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 0):

If using [Knockout Punches](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/), this is fixed automatically by the "Wrapped event callbacks" preprocessor, and you can then use your existing binding and view model. The explanation:

> When binding functions in your model to events, it’s easy to simply provide the function reference to the binding such as `click: $parent.removePlace`. When bound this way, though, the reference to `$parent` is lost; the `removePlace` method will be called with a default `this` value (the current model object).